# How can I sort a 2d list by columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

how can I get rid of these if statements and make it simpler by using a for loop and without using numpy

```
 def sortColumns(grid):
    if grid[0][0] > grid[1][0]:
        grid[0][0],grid[1][0]= grid[1][0],grid[0][0]
    if grid[2][0] < grid[1][0]:
        grid[2][0],grid[1][0]= grid[1][0],grid[2][0]
    if grid[1][0] < grid[0][0]:
        grid[1][0],grid[0][0] = grid[0][0],grid[1][0]

    if grid[0][1] > grid[1][1]:
        grid[0][1],grid[1][1]= grid[1][1],grid[0][1]
    if grid[2][1] < grid[1][1]:
        grid[2][1],grid[1][1]= grid[1][1],grid[2][1]
    if grid[1][1] < grid[0][1]:
        grid[1][1],grid[0][1] = grid[0][1],grid[1][1]

    if grid[0][2] > grid[1][2]:
        grid[0][2],grid[1][2]= grid[1][2],grid[0][2]
    if grid[2][2] < grid[1][2]:
        grid[2][2],grid[1][2]= grid[1][2],grid[2][2]
    if grid[1][2] < grid[0][2]:
        grid[1][2],grid[0][2] = grid[0][2],grid[1][2]

for x in grid:
    for y in x:
        print(str(y).center(3,' '),end= ' ')
    print()
```

example output needs to be similar to this :

```
Enter the number of rows: 3
Enter the number of columns: 3
   -3  58 -46 
   29  40 -65 
   26 -53 -55 
Sorted list by column is 

  -3 -53 -65 
  26  40 -55 
  29  58 -46
```

Comment: get values from column and put in list, sort list using `sort()`, put element from list in column.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and *unpacking* with `*`, you could transpose, *sort* each sublist and then transpose again:

```
>>> lst = [[-3, 58, -46], [29, 40, -65], [26, -53, -55]]
>>> result = zip(*map(sorted, zip(*lst)))
>>> result
[(-3, -53, -65), (26, 40, -55), (29, 58, -46)]
```

In Python 3.x, `result` will be a `zip` object; you'll need call `list` on it.

If you want to keep your results as a list of lists (not tuples), you could do that with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [list(s) for s in zip(*map(sorted, zip(*lst)))]
[[-3, -53, -65], [26, 40, -55], [29, 58, -46]]
```

Comment: is there a way that I can accomplish this using a for loop and not list comprehension